# Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 HTTP Status 404

Tags: tomcat

so i have renamed lib folder where is all jar files by accident and once i renamed that folder back i can't see my website only this message:
[HTTP Satuts 404 -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bDyp.png)

I have googled and found some solutions to it only 1 small problem i run the tomcat server on amazon servers and not locahost i don't know how to solve this problem and for my situation i didn't find any solution.Also i have tried login by putty and restart tomcat but i failed.

Comment: I have managed to solve the main problem, found how to restart tomcat and it kinda helped i used ./catalina.sh stop and than ./catalina.sh start and it started but first request when i enter the page always gives page not found error basically that is 404 error basically i need press f5 and than content loads  i'm running tomcat as non root user any thoughts?

Comment: Please update the question with more information and add some punctuation I cant tell where one sentence ends and another begins thanks